# Value of not yet reached pointer variable

Tags: c

Im curious about an explanation for the following example:

```
void                                         
release(ptr *foo) {
     /* ... */
}

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    goto cleanup;
    ptr *foo = someFunctionAllocatingMemory();

cleanup:
    release(foo);

    return 0;
}
```

What will be the value of foo in the release function? Running that example on an ARM using gcc for compilation gave me NULL. Is that consistent for every architecture / compiler? Can someone explain what is going on here?

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by "gave me NULL"?

Comment: Since you skipped the initialisation it will just be an uninitialised pointer and you will get undefined behaviour if you try to reference it.

Comment: The lifetime of the `foo` object starts at the opening of the block where it is declared but the initialization is done when `foo` is declared, so in your case `foo` is not initialized when `release` is called.